# MYSQL issue - join not enough

Tags: mysql, join

i have 3 tables: `products`, `buyers` and `ratings`.

a buyer can rate i product and this will be saved as a row in ratings (with `buyer_id` and `product_id`) and a buyer can mark one product (at most one favorite product per buyer) as favorite (a binary flag in `ratings`).

i have a report of all buyers and want to add to each row in the report the name of the buyer's favorite product (if he has one), i tried this:

```
SELECT b.*, p.name 
FROM buyers b, products p 
LEFT JOIN ratings r 
    ON r.buyer_id = b.id 
    and r.product_id = p.id 
    and r.isFav=1
```

unfortunately this throws an error (Unknown column 'b.id' in 'on clause'). so i feel that i'm going the wrong way about it.
is there something that can help me accomplish what i need?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: ERROR was: Unknown column 'b.id' in 'on clause'
anyways, bluefeet's answer did the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the any data, one of the big problems is you are mixing `JOIN` syntax, I might rewrite it this way:

```
SELECT b.*, p.name 
FROM buyers b
LEFT JOIN ratings r 
    ON b.id = r.buyer_id
LEFT JOIN  products p 
    ON r.product_id = p.id 
WHERE r.isFav=1
```

Comment: r.isFav=1 should be in the ON-clause, otherwise the left-join will not work

Comment: @Argeman possibly true, it would be easier to write these queries if we could see sample data.

Comment: right, sample data is necessary. But it is definitely true, otherwise your first left join is reduced to a join effictively. Or you have to  append "OR r.isFav IS NULL"